# ng-recaptcha tag <recaptcha> causes error "zone.js: Unhandled Promise rejection" when route changes

Tags: html, angular, typescript, recaptcha

I'm using "ng-recaptcha" on Angular component. Im using inside a form like this:

```js
<form class="form-contact"
        [formGroup]="contactForm"
        #formDirective="ngForm" 
        (ngSubmit)="sendMessage(contactForm, formDirective)">
  <re-captcha class="recaptcha"
              formControlName="captcha"
              siteKey="mysitekey">
  </re-captcha>
</form>
```

Then I send the form to component:

```js
export class AboutComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  contactForm: FormGroup;
  captchaResponse: string;
  private emailSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private emailService: EmailService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.contactForm = new FormGroup({
      captcha: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
    });
  }
  
  ngOnDestroy(): void { 
    if (this.emailSubscription) { this.emailSubscription.unsubscribe(); } 
  }

  sendMessage(contactForm: FormGroup, formDirective: FormGroupDirective) {
    if (contactForm.valid) {
      this.emailSubscription = this.emailService.sendEmail(contactForm.value)
        .subscribe((response: ApiResponse) => {
          if (response.success) {
            console.log(response.message);
            formDirective.resetForm();
            contactForm.reset();
          } else {
            this.alertService.error(response.message);
          }
        }, (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          console.log({status: error.status, error: error.error});
          this.alertService.error('Error sending message. Please try again later or send a direct message.');
        }
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Everything seems to be working fine. However, when route changes (ex. user goes to another page) and the `AboutComponent` is rendered again, an error pops up: `Unhandled Promise rejection: timeout ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: timeout undefined`. I'm 99% sure it's caused by `<re-captcha>` tag because error doesn't show up after removing the tag. Is there a way to render a captcha without errors when route changes (and captcha reloads after im back to component)?

Link to Stackblitz: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-en3spw)

Comment: Looks more like a library issue, it's nice you created a ticket for this: https://github.com/DethAriel/ng-recaptcha/issues/123

Comment: Probably. I wasn't sure at the beggining, but now it makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 2):

This is a temporary and pretty bad fix but it worked for me

```
 // somewhere in your "main.ts" or "app.component.ts"
import { RecaptchaComponent } from 'ng-recaptcha';
RecaptchaComponent.prototype.ngOnDestroy = function() {
  if (this.subscription) {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Read More: https://github.com/DethAriel/ng-recaptcha/issues/123#issuecomment-426112101